# About multiplying two essential singularity containing functions

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find analytic function such that f(z) and g(z) both have essential singularity at z = 0

but when multiplied together they have a pole of order 7.

I honestly do not recognize essential singularity other than e^(1/z) and e(1/z^n)

can't think of it top of my head, all I know is that they have infinite power of laurent

series....how can they become a pole can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

For example, $e^{1/z}$ multiplied by $e^{-1/z}/z^7$ yields $1/z^7$.

Comment: ah I did not think about that thanks I have an idea now....can you give me more example of essential singularity?

Comment: I think the term "essential singularity" is used only for single-valued functions.  That would exclude the logarithm, which is a good thing because, in contrast to what Picard's theorem says about essential singularities, the logarithm does not take all but 3 values in every neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I removed my comment.

Comment: I guess $f(1/z)$ for any $f$ which is non-polynomial and holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ is more or less what @MathMA is asking for.